# Can Selenium select specific characters or words within an element's text?

Tags: python, selenium

Can Selenium (specifically when run from Python) select specific characters or words within an element's text without any more detailed markup? Just a plain string.
I would like to select specific words found by matching string to a variable.

I see that I can use sequence `action.click_and_hold().perform() ... action.release()` The question is how to get to the initial and the end positions? The command `action.move_to_element_with_offset` can potentially do it, but uses coordinates instead position a need span in a characters. I guess in theory it possible to calculate these coordinates using width characters and heights of lines, but that seems to be something unnecessarily cumbersome. Unless I can easily do the opposite action - get coordinate from a character in a specific position in the text. I am a newbie with Selenium. I could not find any commands that can do what I need. I will be surprised if this functionality just does not exist in Selenium. It seems to me that this should be needed for testing. If so, is there some common workaround for this (for example, running JavaScript from Selenium)?

Comment: Often people will extract the sentence, and then use various techniques to extract the information they need from the sentence. If you provide the sentence, or your code with desired output, I can show you with more detail.

Comment: @ScottC I see what you are telling. If I actually just needed to copy that would. The thing is that on the page I am running, selection of a string causes an event followed by a popup containing that exact selected piece of text. Also, after some action, position of the selection is passed to the backend... I did not want to go into all these details in my original question.
Looks it is not doable.

Comment: maybe show your code - it will provide better insight into what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ScottC There is nothing to show. I just would Selenium to do one specific thing, which most likely it cannot do, but I am double-checking that I am not missing something it actualy can do.

Comment: In case you mean the code of the page itself but not the Python Selenium code, I do not have it. I guess I could get the JavaScipt or whatever else is embedded in the HTML itself, but I never went into that, and I do not need to, and probably there are some references to external files that are not available to me, and also it is proprietary.